# Get id of logged in user to show categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table join which handles the user_id and the cat_id and depending on which user is logged in depends on which categories they can see - however, I can only get this working by explicitly typing in the users id into the code and need it to know which user it is logged in:

```
    <?php 

    try{
        $results = $dbh->query("SELECT *
                                FROM cat_List
                                INNER JOIN user_cat_link_table
                                ON cat_List.Cat_ID = user_cat_link_table.Cat_ID
                                WHERE user_cat_link_table.UserID = 10 //HERE IS THE ISSUE!
                                ");

    }catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

    $docs = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($docs as $docs){  

    echo '
        <a href="catView.php?cat_id='.$docs["cat_id"].'">
            <div class="indexBox">
                <div class="indexBoxHeader">
                    <i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size: 2em;"></i></div>
                <div class="indexBoxFooter">
                    <p>'.$docs["cat_title"].'</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        ';}
    ?>
```

The user gets signed in with this script:

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location:home.php");
    exit;
}


    $dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=######;host=localhost', '######', '######');/*Change The Credentials to connect to database.*/
    $email=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['pass'];

    if(isset($_POST) && $email!='' && $password!=''){
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE username=?");
        $sql->execute(array($email));

    while($r=$sql->fetch()){
        $p=$r['password'];
        $p_salt=$r['psalt'];
        $id=$r['id'];
        $email=$r['username'];
        $firstname=$r['firstname'];
        $lastname=$r['lastname'];
    }

        $site_salt="subinsblogsalt"; /*Common Salt used for password storing on site. You can't change it. If you want to change it, change it when you register a user.*/
        $salted_hash = hash('sha256',$password.$site_salt.$p_salt);

    if($p==$salted_hash){
        $_SESSION['user']=$id;
        $_SESSION['username']=$email;
        $_SESSION['firstname']=$firstname;
        $_SESSION['lastname']=$lastname;

        header("Location:home.php");

    }else{
        echo "<h2>Username/Password is Incorrect.</h2>";
        }
    }
?>
```

There are 3 tables, there is the user_login table, a cat_list table and a table which handles the relationship, but the burning issue is getting the script to know who the user is and how those categories which are associated to the user from the rows in the third table.

Comment: **WARNING:** Please use proper [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) methods and do not use SHA256. Due to the pervasiveness of Bitcoin mining, where systems can do tens of trillions of hashes per second, it's basically worthless.

Comment: Is the ID in question stored in `$_SESSION['user']`?  If so, just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using sessions so in the php page where you need to use the user id just do:

```
<?php
session_start();
$actusr = $_SESSION['user'];
    try{
        $results = $dbh->query("SELECT *
                                FROM cat_List
                                INNER JOIN user_cat_link_table
                                ON cat_List.Cat_ID = user_cat_link_table.Cat_ID
                                WHERE user_cat_link_table.UserID = '$actusr'");
```

Comment: `$actusr` that stands to be a string. If it is in fact a string, it needs to be quoted. *Just saying*. Best to cover all the bases ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right! typo error. Edit my answer to fix!

Comment: It wasn't necessarily a typo. The session id could be an integer, and we don't know that for certain. As I said, it's best to cover all the bases. I'd of made a note at the bottom saying that, if it's a string, then to quote it ;-) *Cheers* - Now we'll see if the OP accepts it. :-) buongiorno/buona sera.

Comment: @Fred-ii- now I remember, you speak a bit of italian! :)

Comment: si Lelio, io studiare la lingua Italiana. I can read it quite well and listen very well, but still difficulty building my own sentences. I'm only a year into it, but I would advance faster if I were in an Italian environment, which there aren't many around here. I would have to travel a bit further out of town in order to in "The Italian Village". ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- maybe here is off topic but if you want to do some conversation we can arrange some on skype. BTW where are you from?

Comment: ah peccato, I don't have skype. I'm from Quebec, si... je suis francophone. which explains why I can understand Italian rather well ;-)

Comment: Nice to see that green ticky ;-) *benissimo!*

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your second script, you save the logged in user id in the $_SESSION['user'] global variable. 
So you just have to change your query to a prepared statement like so:

```
session_start();

try{
        $results = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *
                                FROM cat_List
                                INNER JOIN user_cat_link_table
                                ON cat_List.Cat_ID = user_cat_link_table.Cat_ID 
                               WHERE user_cat_link_table.UserID = :user_id //HERE IS THE ISSUE! "); 
$dbh->execute(array(':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']));

}...
```

to dynamically select the category depending on wich user is logged in.

Comment: if the two scripts are in two different pages you have to start the session on the second page to get this working.